# Doctrine - Left Join with LIMIT

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, greatest-n-per-group, dql

I Have two tables : Post and Comment in a Many to One relation.

```
table post                        table comment
p_id | name   | u_id              c_id | p_id | comment        | date
1    | post 1 | 1                 1    | 1    | blah blah blah | 2017-01-01
2    | post 2 | 2                 2    | 1    | blah blah blah | 2017-01-04
3    | post 3 | 1                 3    | 2    | blah blah blah | 2017-01-07
...                               ...
```

I would like to retrieve all Posts by u_id with their 3 Last comments ordered by date.

I would do :

```
SELECT p, c 
FROM p
LEFT JOIN p.comments c WITH c.date IN (SELECT c2.date) FROM App\Bundle\Entity\Comment as c2 WHERE c2.post = p.p_id ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 3)
WHERE p.user = 1
```

But doctrine doesn't allow LIMIT, how i can do that ?

Comment: Dude, why won't you use raw SQL for that?

Comment: You can get your posts alone from query builder and when loop through these posts call the getter method for associated comments and just show 3 latest comments

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to to that is by using the function

`setMaxResults($limit);`

I give you an example :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

$qb
  ->innerJoin('a.advert', 'adv')
  ->addSelect('adv')
;

$qb->setMaxResults($limit);

return $qb
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult()
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

As I known `QueryBuilder::setMaxResult()` work only on primary table not on subquery.

IMHO it's best to write it in classic SQL, where you have better control on subquery and what is joining. In this case you get plain array not array of objects with relation. But, this is better when you need only to show lists of posts and not interact with single entity. In this case getting entire object hydrating one by one populating from DQL, is quite slower then using plain array from SQL.

You could do this like that:

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ...');
$stmt->execute($parameters);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```